# Convert jQuery .each method to lodash equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

I have the following code:

```
$.each(codes, function(item, code) {
  if (code.levelId === vm.circle.level2Id) {
    vm.level2Id = code.levelId;
    return false;
  } else {
    vm.level2Id = "";
  }
});
```

How can I convert this code using lodash?

Comment: @Satpal, `_.each` is deprecated, use `_.forEach`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows,

```
_.forEach(codes, function(code) {
  if (code.levelId === vm.circle.level2Id) {
    vm.level2Id = code.levelId;
    return false;
  } else {
    vm.level2Id = "";
  }
});
```